# Why can I only encounter Beedrill?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

I just downloaded Pokemon Ash Grey and after the Beedrill swarm in Viridian Forest, everywhere I go the only wild Pokemon I encounter is Beedrill.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

#### Background

Pokemon Ash Grey closely follows Ash Ketchum's story as it is shown in the anime.

In the anime Season 1 Episode 4 - *Challenge of the Samurai* , while traveling through Viridian Forest Ash encounters and accepts the challenge to battle 'Samurai' (this is the Metapod vs Metapod episode). As part of the plot, their battle is interrupted by a swarm of Beedrill, Ash's Metapod is taken by the Beedrill, and Ash and the others take refuge at Samurai's home.

#### What's happening?

To implement this episode/event into the game, some creative license is taken. Instead of being chased by a horde of Beedrill to Samurai's home, a short animation is shown of several Beedrill flying overhead, before control is given back to the player and you can move freely again.

Internally however, a 'flag' is set so that until the end of the 'Beedrill' event, all Pokemon encounters in tall grass will **only** produce Beedrill.

Now there's nothing stopping you from progressing further in the story **without** ending the Beedrill event.* I suspect this is what's happened here - you've probably simply bypassed the trigger to turn it off.

#### How do I stop it?

To complete the Beedrill event, you must enter Samurai's house in Viridian Forest and speak with him. From memory, depending on whether you had a Metapod in your party when you triggered the Beedrill event, you may have to go rescue it from deeper in the forest as well.

Once you have completed the event, Pokemon spawns should occur normally again.

<sub>* I suspect this is an oversight, given that this is a fan mod it's not surprising that you can bypass stuff like this. In regular Pokemon games your path would normally be completely blocked until you triggered the right thing to allow progression.</sub>